# (Editied): Error executing query in metabase: (ERROR: syntax error at or near "and" Position: 33)

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I am running a very simple query in Metabase, however, I am getting an error.
Following is the code I am running:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM order_order
[[where date_placed between {{from}} and {{to}}]]
and {{partner_id}}
```

Following is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "and" Position: 33
```

I have been trying multiple ways to get this fixed, but couldn't get this to work. I would appreciate your help with this query. I don't see a problem with the query tho. What am I missing?

[Attaching image for refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x3QW.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Do not use images for textual information. Copy an paste the text into your question.

Comment: That's not an actual SQL statement, but a SQL template. Please include the exact SQL statement that is executed in PostgreSQL.

Comment: At what point does the error occur, when the template is created or when the query is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
SELECT user_id  
FROM order_order  
where
{{partner_id}}
[[and {{date}}]]
```

then use an advanced date query to do the between part?

All from memory so hope I'm not way off.

Answer (score 0):

The statement inside the [[ ]] in your query is only used when from or to variables have a selected value. That means that when both from and to are not set (no value selected) your query will be the following:

> ```
> SELECT user_id
> FROM order_order
> and {{partner_id}}
> ```

hence the error.
In order to resolve it you should set the where clause to always true and then have the conditional statements that you want. Here is an example:

```
SELECT user_id  
FROM order_order  
where true  
[[and date_placed between {{from}} and {{to}}]] 
and {{partner_id}}
```